# java if condition not working correctly

Tags: java, if-statement

I am doing a simple check on combobox if value of combobox is selected or not but when second condition is true then no notification is shows and when first condition is true then the notification is show here is the code.

```
if(cboContactType.getValue() == null || cboCountry.getValue() == null){
  Notification.show("Contact type and country can't be empty");
} else if(cboContactType.getValue().equals("Email")) {
    if(txtEmail.getValue() == null) {
      Notification.show("Email can'nt be empty");
    }
}
```

Tell me what is the mistake. Thanks :)

Comment: the mistake is most likely your code not working with the values you think. remember: "" is not the same as null

Comment: Debug your code and you'll understand.

Comment: post values with which you are testing.

Comment: I recommend using something like StringUtils.isEmpty() instead of doing null checks from org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils or equivalent

Comment: it's a very simple if-else block. just debug to see how it works. if some notification is not shown - your if or else body is skipped because condition is not met

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(cboContactType.getValue() == null || cboContactType.getValue().equals("") || cboCountry.getValue() == null || cboCountry.getValue().equals("")){
```

Or just debug (or simply add System.out.println("Value is: "+cboContactType.getValue()); to your code and you'll see the real value